# Should I use preload_app with Puma on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, preload, puma

I am running a small Rails app on Heroku with one dyno and several Puma workers.

The [Puma docs](https://github.com/puma/puma) say:

> General rule is to use preload_app when your workers die often and
>   need fast starts. If you don’t have many workers, you probably should
>   not use preload_app.

This suggests that I should not use `preload_app!` in my `config/puma.rb`. However, I have a few unanswered questions:

- When do my workers die? Will they be reaped and re-forked after a certain number of requests? How can I monitor this?
- How do I know if my workers need fast starts?

It's clear that `preload_app!` should save resources when using many workers, but I don't see the disadvantage of using it even with a small number of workers.

Heroku's [recommended config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#config) for "a simple Rails application" includes `preload_app!` but they don't offer any guidance on when not to use it.

When should `preload_app!` not be used, and why? (Ignoring the phased restart issue.)

Comment: I have the same question and my google fu hasn't turned up anything extra.

Answer (score 3):

Besides starting worker fast, `preload_app!` also saves memory thanks to [Copy on Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) feature introduced in Ruby 2.0.

You can read this [great write-up from Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/matz_highlights_ruby_2_0_at_waza) introducing the idea of copy-on-write in Ruby:

> Copy on Write or COW is an optimization that can reduce the memory footprint of a Ruby process when it is copied. Instead of allocating duplicate memory when a process is forked, COW allows multiple processes to share the same memory until one of the processes needs to modify a piece of information.

Thus no matter how many works you have, it's always recommended to enable `preload_app!` if possible.